# Scrapy and ajax requests to get hidden elements

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting started with Scrapy and there is a website I'm trying to get data from. Specifically the phone number element which is inside a `div` element that has an id. I noticed that if I send a request to this page I can get it.

https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/6CLxXv/0 
so basiclay the base url would be https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/ID/0/
and 6CLxXv = ID for this example.

How do I scrape all the `div` elements, concatenate them with the base url and then retrieve the phone number element ?

Here is the code used :

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Compose

from otomoto.items import OtomotoItem


def filter_out_array(x):
    x = x.strip()
    return None if x == '' else x


def remove_spaces(x):
    return x.replace(' ', '')


def convert_to_integer(x):
    return int(x)


class OtomotoCarLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    features_out = MapCompose(filter_out_array)
    price_out = Compose(TakeFirst(), remove_spaces, convert_to_integer)


class OtomotoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'otomoto'
    start_urls = ['https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for car_page in response.css('.offer-title__link::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(car_page, self.parse_car_page)

        for next_page in response.css('.next.abs a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
    @inline_requests
    def parse_car_page(self, response):
        property_list_map = {
            'Marka pojazdu': 'brand',
            'Model pojazdu': 'model',
            'Rok produkcji': 'year',
        }
        contact_response = yield scrapy.Request(url_number) # how do i get the specific phone number url 
        number = # parse the responose here ? then add load it in the loader
        loader = OtomotoCarLoader(OtomotoItem(), response=response)

        for params in response.css('.offer-params__item'):
            property_name = params.css('.offer-params__label::text').extract_first().strip()
            if property_name in property_list_map:
                css = params.css('.offer-params__value::text').extract_first().strip()
                if css == '':
                    css = params.css('a::text').extract_first().strip()
                loader.add_value(property_list_map[property_name], css)

        loader.add_css('price', '.offer-price__number::text')
        loader.add_css('price_currency', '.offer-price__currency::text')

        loader.add_css('features', '.offer-features__item::text')
        loader.add_value('url', response.url)
        loader.add('phone number', number)    # here i want to add the phone number to the rest of the elements 
        yield loader.load_item()
```

note : i was able to find the following link "https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/6CLxXv/0" by checking the page xhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into `xpath` https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/selectors.html. There you should find feasable solutions to select the distinct elements you need. Eg. selecting all the elements `divs` of a parent `div` which have an `id`-attribute starting with `a` ... `"//div[@id='a']/div/"`

This way you can put your results into a list. The latter - extracting the numbers from the list and building the base string is simple string concatenation.

The same counts for scraping the ids. Find unique indicators, so you can make sure that those are the elements you need. Eg. following content. Is the id you need different from others on the page which you don't need?

```py
for idx in collected_list:
    url = 'https.com/a/b/'+idx+'/0'
```

EDIT:

I see. Your code is quite advanced. I could get more into it, if I would have the full code, but from that I see you use this html element:

```html
<a href="" class="spoiler seller-phones__button" data-path="multi_phone" data-id="6D5zmw" data-id_raw="6074401671" title="Kontakt Rafał" data-test="view-seller-phone-1-button" data-index="0" data-type="bottom">
    <span class="icon-phone2 seller-phones__icon"></span>
    <span data-test="seller-phone-2" class="phone-number seller-phones__number">694 *** ***</span>
    <span class="separator">-</span>
    <span class="spoilerAction">Wyświetl numer</span>
</a>
```

The `data-id` is what you need to extract, because its the ID you are looking for and can simple apply to:

```py
new_request_url = "https://www.otomoto.pl/ajax/misc/contact/multi_phone/"+id+"/0/"
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the time you took to post this response am afraid i  still don't understand how exactly I can implement what you said

Comment: @Felix okay. Let;s recap. You have multiple `<div id='unique''></div>` <- with xpath you need to select all `div`s which have an `id` attribute and then extract the text, which will be a list. Second. You need to build the url request string? So from your initial list you you always put them into a string, which just changes the `id` uri path (string concatenation) and then *third) you have the final string you can make the request with. Otherwise please edit, give more examples of the html and explanations in your post.

Comment: hey @user2853437  again thank you for your response  i appreciate  you helping me out , i updated my original question with the code i used i commented the bits i am having trouble with

Comment: @Felix I also edit my answer. I hope it's what you need?